# Displays from 01 - 09 but it resets back to 02 instead of 10

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a 4 digit 7 segment LED using Arduino Uno R3. I tried to make a conversion of 4-bit binary into decimal values if a button was pressed. It did count the decimal values from 1-9 however instead to getting to 10, it resets back to the value of 2. Still trying to figure out how to make it go until the decimal value of 15 if 4 buttons are pressed. Here are my codes:

```
const int buttonPins[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
const int sevSegPins[] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
const int dPins[] = {5, 4};
const int D1 = 4;
const int D2 = 5;

const byte digitValues[10][7] = {
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, // 0
  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 1
  {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, // 2
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, // 3
  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, // 4
  {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, // 5
  {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // 6
  {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 7
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // 8
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}  // 9
};

int buttonClicks[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int binaryValue = 0;
int decimalValue = 0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize button pins
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pinMode(buttonPins[i], INPUT);
    digitalWrite(buttonPins[i], HIGH); // Enable internal pull-up resistors
  }

  // Initialize 7-segment display pins
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    pinMode(sevSegPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pinMode(dPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  // Initialize Serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Read button clicks
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (digitalRead(buttonPins[i]) == LOW) {
      // Button is pressed
      if (buttonClicks[i] == 0) {
        // Increment the binary value when the button is first pressed
        binaryValue ^= (1 << i);
        buttonClicks[i] = 1;
      }
    } else {
      // Button is not pressed
      buttonClicks[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  // Convert binary to decimal
  decimalValue = binaryToDecimal(binaryValue);

  // Display decimal value on 7-segment display
  displayDecimal(decimalValue);
}

int binaryToDecimal(int binary) {
  int decimal = 0;
  int base = 1;
  while (binary > 0) {
    int lastDigit = binary % 10;
    decimal += lastDigit * base;
    base *= 2;
    binary /= 10;
  }
  return decimal;
}

void displayDecimal(int value) {
  for (int digit = 0; digit < 2; digit++) {
    // Extract the digit value
    int digitValue = value % 10;
    value /= 10;

    // Display the digit on the 7-segment display
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      digitalWrite(sevSegPins[i], digitValues[digitValue][i]);
    }

    // Enable the current digit
    digitalWrite(dPins[digit], HIGH);
    delay(5); // Adjust delay based on your requirements
    digitalWrite(dPins[digit], LOW);
  }
}
```

Everyting is working, only then the value does not exceed greater than 9.

Possible solution to display the remaining values, 10-15, through the 4 digit 7 segment diplay.

Comment: All values are stored as binary.  All your binaryToDecimal function does is copy the variable.  You could write `decimalValue = binaryValue;` and it would do the same thing.  Decimal, Hex, and Binary are representations of numbers that are shown on the screen to humans.  In the computer it's **ALL** binary